# .NET 5 Blazor ServerSide AND WebAssembly (hybrid) with WebAPI Authentication?

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Is there a way to use the default Authentication (.NET 5 / Identity-Server) with Blazor ServerSide **and** Blazor WebAssembly in a hybrid manner?
I want to have a Blazor Project, which can be switched between ClientSide (WebAssembly) and ServerSide, to keep the Client the same, I want to use the WebAPI on ClientSide **and** ServerSide. I started with ServerSide (better debugging and better performance for tables *) and maybe switch to ClientSide later (if the performance will be better).

**Please do not start discussing about what is better or if YOU maybe have a good performance with WebAssembly, then you don't have many nested components like component based tables.*

I did test so many combinations, but can't get it to work, but let's start with the basic:

- Create Blazor WebAssembly Project (ASP.Net Core hosted)
- Use .NET 5 with Authentication (accounts)
- Edit the Server startup.cs (like below)
- Edit the Client program.cs (like below)
- Add the "_Host.cshtml" to "\Server\Pages" (like below)

**Startup.cs (Server)**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddIdentityServer().AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();
    
    // SERVER SIDE SUPPORT
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddApiAuthorization();
    if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
    {
        services.AddScoped(s =>
        {
            var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
            return new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new System.Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
            };
        });
    }
    // --

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        
        // SERVER-SIDE SUPPORT
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host"); //endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        // --
    });
}
```

**Program.cs (Client)**

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    //builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

    builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorSwitchWithSec2.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

    // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("BlazorSwitchWithSec2.ServerAPI"));

    builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

**_Host.cshtml (Server)**

```
@page "/"
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        @if (Request.QueryString.Value.ToLower().Contains("mode=client"))
        {
            <title>WebApp (CE)</title>
        }
        else
        {
            <title>WebApp (SE)</title>
        }
        <base href="~/" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
        @if (Request.QueryString.Value.ToLower().Contains("mode=client"))
        {
            <component type="typeof(BlazorSwitchWithSec2.Client.App)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
            <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
            <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
            <script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>
        }
        else
        {
            <component type="typeof(BlazorSwitchWithSec2.Client.App)" render-mode="Server" />
            <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
            <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

If I try to register or login via WebAssembly or Server, I get this error:
`` Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ServerAuthenticationStateProvider' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IRemoteAuthenticationService`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState]' ``

Maybe also this helps: I tried something different like using the services from the client, one combination seemed to work with controllers without [Authorize] attribute, but with it, I got a error like `Unable to parse ...` - the result was a login url (this is why the parsing didn't work). I can't post the code, because I tested too much and the project isn't working anymore.

Without any Authentication everything works and I could send a token to the WebAPI to create my own login system. But I want to try the default one.

Comment: Although you program them the same, server side and wasm are quite different. As the wasm runs naively in the client browser, a different approach for authentication is needed.

Comment: I know, the default code works fine on client side (if I don't change anything). There is "just" a missing part for the server side to tell "use your cookie / storage and send your data to the api". I mean the default serverside code is working also (with auth), but without API access. And the (code) difference between them seems minimal.

Comment: Have you ever found the solution? Been dealing with the same issue

Comment: @user2657943 Not really, see my comment on the other answer. I used the builtin Authentication on the API (serverside) to login users and create a token. Is send this token with every request and check the combination of user id and token with a cookie. The token is a custom solution, so only the login is default code. There are also some example hybrid projects, but they are very big and hard to understand IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t like the approach of BlazorServer referencing BlazorWasm. I prefer to have both BlazorServer and BlazorWasm projects reference a dll(rdl) which contains the App, makes it a bit more clear that both are using a shared codebase and it avoids BlazorServer pulling in unnecessary dependencies from BlazorWasm.
you can check this link
**https://github.com/mostafaefcih/BlazorDaulMode**
or check blazor getting started course on plaursight

Comment: I tried something similar like you, it's a very clean way. But didn't figure out how to share the www stuff like the CSS-files between the 2 projects. It's too late for me to go back ;) I now have a single instance running with custom auth, but I can switch between Server and Wasm on runtime.

Comment: @StewieG u can add it in the root folder in each project(Wasm->index.html or host.cshtml in blzaor server )

Answer (score 0):

These Blazor Train videos from Carl Franklin may help you.

Blazor Synchronicity; Develop Server & WASM Apps Simultaneously

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkYQDPXw__c

Blazor Synchronicity 5.0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHzIWOfmqzg

Comment: I did this kind of setup nearly 20 times, but you still have the problem with Authentication, because on serverside you have SignalR and on Wasm you have Http. The only working way so far, was to use a own login system (which sends an Token on EVERY request).

Comment: I see, Out of interest why don't you concentrate on server-side for now with the knowledge that as you are utilising an API the switch to client-side would not be arduous should it prove advantageous to do so in the future?

Comment: This is what I do at the moment . But now I'm at a point where I need a file upload, As far as I know, this is only possible via Http / Web-API, so I need some workaround agian.

Comment: In danger of answering every question with a link to Blazor Train however I'm wondering whether there would be anything of help in Episode 37? https://blazortrain.com/ Note that you can download the source code for both WASM and Server-Side